# Spring Data JPA flush does not save changes to database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following code that first check record and if found delete that record and flush changes to the database. However, when I debug, I see that it does not reflect changes to the database when debugger hit the next code block (`final Stock stock = new Stock();`).

```
@Transactional
public CommandDTO createOrUpdate(StockRequest request) {
    stockRepository.findByBrandUuidAndProductUuid(
                 request.getBrandUuid(), 
                 request.getProductUuid())
            .ifPresent(stock -> {
                stockRepository.delete(stock);
                stockRepository.flush();
            });

    final Stock stock = new Stock();
    if (request.isOutOfStock()) {
        stock.setBrandUuid(request.getBrandUuid());
        stock.setProductUuid(request.getProductUuid());
        stock.save(stock);
    }
    return CommandDTO.builder().uuid(stock.getUuid()).build();
}
```

So, what is the mistake in this approach?

Comment: And it should because? The transaction hasn't committed so changes aren't persisted nor visible. Flush isn't the same as committing.

Comment: All flushing does is run the sql. Committing makes the changes visible. Leaving the method triggers the commit.

Comment: So, how can I commit the changes so that I can add a new record without violating constraint?

Comment: @M.Deinum I also created a separate delete method using `@Transactional` annotation, but despite this, the record is not updated on database after code hits and out from delete method. I think it may be due to that there is a  `@Transactional` in the `createOrUpdate` method. Any idea?

Comment: @NathanHughes Amigo? Any reply?

Comment: You have 1 transaction which is around the service method, everything needs to be inside the method. Also why the delete and add again? Why not just update the existing one.

Comment: Normally I use createOrUpdate approach. But there are several conditions for delete, create and update in this method. Then instead of checking all of these conditions, I just wanted to simply delete first and then create or update based on request value. Is that still bad idea? Any suggestion pls?

Answer (score -1):

JPA doesn't supports final field.

You can use two alternative solution for immutable class.

1. use @Immutable at entity class.
2. change entity class fields having only a getter.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question at hand.

Comment: @M.Deinum Why do not you post your suggestion instead of just negative comment?

Comment: @M.Deinum I also created a separate delete method using `@Transactional` annotation, but despite this, the record is not updated on database after code hits and out from delete method. I think it may be due to that there is a  `@Transactional` in the ``createOrUpdate` method. Any idea?